# How do I create matrix through VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I need to create a matrix by using a VBA function.

The matrix should be size should be `2(n-1)*2(n-1)`, where `n=1,2,3,...`
It should appear in `cells(i, j)`

I can't find the problem of my code.
Please help me.

```
Function matrix(n, i, j)
    Do While n > 0
        For x = 0 To 2 * (n - 1)
            For y = 0 To 2 * (n - 1)
                Cells(i + x, j + y) = n
            Next
        Next
        matrix = n
    Loop
End Function
```

When n=1, the matrix should appear 1(1*1)matrix.
When n=2, the matrix should appear

```
222  
222   
222 (a 3*3 matrix)
```

When n=3, the matrix should appear

```
33333  
33333   
33333 (a 5*5 matrix)
```

etc...

Comment: What happens when you debug your code? I can tell you that `n` is a fix number, so if you put `n` everywhere, your matrix will be filled with the same number everywhere. So now it's up to you: instead of putting `n` in your matrix, it should be something, based on `x` and `y`. Good luck.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • Please [edit] your question to improve it. Tell us what is wrong with your code. Whet does your code actually do and what did you expect. Show a [mcve] how you call this function and the input values for `n`, `i` and `j` as well as an exaple of the output you expect for these values.

Comment: Note that if the size of the matrix should be `2(n-1)` and your loop starts at `0` you must subtract `1` from the size: `For x = 0 To 2 * (n - 1)` needs to be `For x = 0 To 2 * (n - 1) - 1`

Comment: You are returning `n`, not the `Cells` that you're populating.

Comment: I need to have
when n=1
The matrix will be 1
When n=2
the matrix will be 
(222
222
222)(3*3)matrix of 2

Comment: You need to have what when `n = 1`?

Comment: Please read the links I gave in my comment above and answer **all** the questions by [edit]ing your original question. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: When I do the function, excel shows me "There are one or more circular references where a formula refers to its own cell either directly or indirectly. This might cause them to calculate incorrectly. Try removing or changing these references, or moving the formulas to different cells."

Comment: @文子小 do you call the function in a formula? Or by VBA (then please show the code how you call it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop for that. Since the whole data is the same you can write the complete matrix at once.

Also since it does not return anything it should be procedure (`Sub`) and not a function.

```
Public Sub CreateMatrix(ByVal n As Long, ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long)
    Cells(i, j).Resize(1 + 2 * (n - 1), 1 + 2 * (n - 1)).Value = n
End Sub
```

'run the procedure

```
Public Sub Test()
    'select the cell where you want the matrix to start then run this procedure 

    Dim n As Long
    n = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter size of matrix n=", Title:="Create Matrix", Type:=1)

    If n > 0 Then
        CreateMatrix n, Selection.Row, Selection.Column
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I need to directly make a function but not using sub

Comment: @文子小 That cannot be done by a function.

Comment: Why is a matrix can't be created through function??
I'm still green in VBA

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: So, if i follow your code, i just need to add inputbox to input the values??

Comment: @文子小 Check my answer again I provided another example. Therefore you first select the cell where your matrix should start, and then run the procedure `Test()`. It will ask for the matrix size and create it.

Comment: Note I fixed the `Resize` formula as there was a `+1` missing too.

Comment: I found that can it possible to be an array function @Pᴇʜ??

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense because then you would need to fill the range of size `2 * (n - 1)` with that array formula. In order to do that you would need first to calculate that size manually and then select that range and enter the array formula. So you can as well instead enter `n` which would be much easier and you don't need the array formula anymore. So that's why I said it doesn't make any senes at all.

Answer (score -2):

Please replace the 'Do While...Loop' with 'If' condition, otherwise it is creating infinite loop. Please refer to below code block. It worked for me.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Call CreateMatrix(5, 3, 5)
 
'
End Sub
 
Public Function CreateMatrix(n, i, j)
    If n > 0 Then
        For x = 1 To (2 * (n - 1))
            For y = 1 To (2 * (n - 1))
                Cells(i + x-1, j + y-1) = n
            Next y
        Next x
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: Note this will not start in 3, 5 but in 4, 6 because `x = 1` and `y = 1`.

Comment: What do you mean this worked for you? Where is `Cells` being defined? There's nothing being returned from `CreateMatrix`.

Comment: A function that does not return anything must be a `Sub`.

Comment: In VBA a function without any return type is supported. In such a case Variant is returned. Also "Call Function_Name()" is used to call the function. And VBA is used in excel/Access. In Excel Cells(i,j) refer to a cell in a sheet.

Comment: But there is no sense in returning an **empty** `Variant` and that is what `CreateMatrix` returns. Even more that you use `Call CreateMatrix(5, 3, 5)` shows that you don't use whatever your function would return. Therefore it is usless to be a function and has to be a `Sub`.